# How to check if the html element exist in web page in java

Tags: java, html

I want to check if an html element exist in a webpage by using java and giving the relevant xpath.

```
<div class="groupWrapper">
    <div class="groupHeader">
        <div class="name"> John</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Xpath and What returns is not string and I do not know how to compare the text inside of a div element which is a string (John) to the value xpath returns. by using AssertEquals or anyother thing?

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='groupWrapper']/div[@class='groupHeader']/div[@class='name']/div[contains(text())]);
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public static boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, By by) {
  try {
    driver.findElement(by);
    return true;  // Success!
  } catch (NoSuchElementException ignored) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Where the webdriver is a driver for the browser you are using.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

You can get the text from the div like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='name']/text()"));
String text = element.getText();
```

The cssSelector can get `<div id="someId">` with driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#someId")); and `<div class="someClass">` with cssSelector(".someClass");